# Shadow not displayed in CardView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-cardview

I am developing an android application in which I have used the `cardview` as  the grid item of `GridView`.

I am facing an Issue in displaying the shadow for the `cardview` if I use also the background image for the `cardview`.

**Code Snippet**:

**grid_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_item_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#80000000"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/sample_expert_prof_pic"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#8525272a"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:text="Shankar Venkat"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"

                    android:textSize="@dimen/grid_name_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tags"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="#finance# accounts"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/grid_tags_size" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have increased the `cardElevation` from `2dp` to `10dp`. It shows the shadow in the Design Preview in Android Studio . But not working when deployed to real device.

**UPDATE** :

**The Screenshot of Grid Item** [image: here]

Please anyone help me to find the solution.

Comment: use attribute app:elevation="4dp" instead of card_view:cardElevation="2dp"

Comment: use android:elevation="4dp" instead.

Comment: I have tried both app:elevation="4dp" and android:elevation="4dp" . But not working :-(

Comment: which device you are using?

Comment: Mi 4 which runs on Marshmallow

Comment: try with hardwareAccelerated = true

Comment: I have tried it also in Manifest file . But no breakthrough @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Comment: try to `clean` the project and `rebuild` it.

Comment: try removing attribute card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#80000000" and card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" and keep app:elevation="4dp"

Comment: @RakeshL Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: I have tried it . But not working

Comment: attach your screen shots what you are getting right now !

Comment: seems correct but its strange why it will not reflect !!! any ways ,one quick solution for you .there is one background property is available for card view , use that and create one XML file with shape like rectangle, color and shadow effect for it and set it as background for your linear layout.

Comment: if not getting feel free to ask ...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your real device is Lollipop device.

Try adding card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" to your xml and shadows will appear.

Comment: My device is running with Marshmallow .I have tried card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" but not working :-(